# How to create a graph from a maze

Tags: java, graph, maze, minimum-spanning-tree

I wanted to implement some graph and spanning tree stuff I learned in class this week, so I created a maze generation algorithm based of of Prim's algorithm. Now, I am try to create an algorithm to solve the mazes efficiently. So far, I've made a flood fill which eventually solves the maze, but is very inefficient. I am now trying to find a way to convert the maze into a graph in order to use Dijkstra's algorithm or DFS, but I'm stumped. The maze is stored in a binary array, where 1 is a wall and 0 is an open space. The maze always starts on the only 0 in the first line and ends on the only zero in the last line. The maze is stored as shown bellow.

```
static int maze2[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                        {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                        {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                        {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
```

Comment: Just generate a graph node for each cell of your matrix (actually only for the zeros), connect each pair of adjacent nodes (i.e., both entries of the matrix are zero) and search a path from the start to the end node. Where in this process are you stuck?

Comment: A maze is essentially a graph. Just treat each integer as a node and their neighbors are all the integers 1 space away from it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *convert* the maze into a graph.  You just *think* of it as a graph.

When you write your algorithm (BFS, DFS, etc.), you only need:

- A way to identify a node - (row,column) pairs work fine, or you can use a single integer row*WIDTH+column.
- A way to find adjacent nodes - just check the neighboring cells in the matrix.